# Dell XPS 15 9560 - SSD Not Recognized

Tags: boot, ssd, bios

I have my computer dual booted with Kali Linux, and I've had it so for some time now.  The other day, all of a sudden, my computer wouldn't boot.  It stuck on the Dell logo for about 5 minutes and finally said "No bootable devices found".  In BIOS, it's not listed.  I've tried secure and non-secure, UEFI and legacy, all the combos, nothing.  To clarify my issue:

- SSD is not recognized by BIOS
- SSD is not recognized by other operating systems (live USB i still had from installation isn't seeing it)
- When I take the SSD out (physically), the computer boots immediately to the USB, or boots immediately and goes to BIOS (nothing is found).  But when it's in, though it doesn't recognize it, it takes *forever* to get anywhere- even when I hit F12 it sticks on the loading screen for several minutes before finally entering the BIOS screen.

The dual-boot setup was working fine until this happened.  I'm not sure what caused it but I would rather fix it myself if possible than have Dell do it for me.

Comment: Have you done any testing on the SSD? (Maybe the SSD is failing)

Comment: I've tried but it is literally like it doesn't exist.  I ran diagnostics and it just said no disk was detected

Comment: That... usually a red flag for me of a failed SSD (or failed Mobo->HD connector).. do you have other system you can use to test it? Or just run Dell Diagnostic (which should be built in) and if it generates any error code - and your system still under warranty - Dell should honor their own error code.